# reload jquery after ajax-form submission

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this working jquery on my webpage

```
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (!$('.normal').length) {
    $('#special').addClass("yellowstone");  }
});
}(jQuery));
```

the selector "normal" is loaded when a form is submitted, but the form works with ajax, an because of that the whole page is not reloaded  -> my script is not changing the class.

How to change that the class is changing after the form submission?

Comment: Change the class in success of your ajax

Comment: Your class is only being added on docready. You need to do it after the content changes in .normal. Put the same check in your $.ajax call's "complete" function.

Comment: @deepu "success" won't catch errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
url:"yoururl",
type:"post",
dataType:"json",
success:function(){
//Do changing the class here
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try at the ajax form submit success

```
$.ajax({
  -----//Own stuff   
  success:function(){
       if (!$('.normal').length) {
          $('#special').addClass("yellowstone");  
       }
   }
 });
```

Comment: what do you mean with "own stuff?"